How to loop through a list and create sublists once a condition is met?
If given a list such as:
test = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']   

and a user given number, say:
num = 2

How do I loop through the list and make sublists every time we arrive at the given number? In other words I want to split the list into elements of num which in this case is 2 and create sublists that contain 2 elements.
For example the desired list I want to create is:
test = [['1','1'], ['1','1'], ['1','1']]

Lets say there was a situation where:
num = 3

then the desired list would be:
test = [['1', '1', '1'], ['1','1','1']]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!
for nums in test:
    pass


It's worth pointing out that you don't exactly need to loop through the list to get what you want. You can calculate the start and end points of each chunk just using math based on num and the length of the list. I say that partly because of the title: Before reading the question, I thought you wanted some sort of grouping like in this question: How can I find same values in a list and group together a new list?

one possible solution would be to slice the list into chunks based on num in a list comprehension:
num = 2
test = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']  

out = [test[i:i + num] for i in range(0, len(test), num)]

Output:
[['1', '1'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '1']]

Explanation:
range(0, len(test), num) is equivalent to range(start, stop, step) so it will produce 3 iterations: 0,2,4 since stop is exclusive in the range
test[i:i + num] creates a slice of test starting at index i and ending at i + num
When i = 0, it returns test[0:2], which is ['1', '1']
When i = 2, it returns test[2:4], which is ['1', '1'].
When i = 4, it returns test[4:6], which is ['1', '1'].

@user19077881 That's actually why it doesn't work for such cases.

The recipe list in the itertools docs has a function to do that.
def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks."
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') → ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') → ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') → ABC DEF
    iterators = [iter(iterable)] * n
    match incomplete:
        case 'fill':
            return zip_longest(*iterators, fillvalue=fillvalue)
        case 'strict':
            return zip(*iterators, strict=True)
        case 'ignore':
            return zip(*iterators)
        case _:
            raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')

